# Interpreting rsync command

Tags: linux, terminal, rsync

as I am very new to rsync, I came across this code somewhere in the server and decided to try it out. It was a dry-run but there are a few parts within this line that I do not understand.

Do correct me if my interpretation below are wrong :x

```
find -name "*.jpg" | xargs -I icon sudo rsync -azuvhE -n icon tango:/jobs/prime/Item/icon
```

Firstly, I understand the first part of `find -name "*.jpg"` and it is looking for any .jpg files within the directory stated.

But I do not understand the meaning of `|` and `xargs -I icon`..  For the latter part, I presume it is like defining `icon` as a variable?

Then as for the last part, as I am crossing referencing between 2 servers (alphis which I am currently on) and tango, I presume it is referencing against the tango/jobs/prime/Item/icon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   find -name "*.jpg" | \     # find jpeg files (assume no white space)
          xargs -I icon \     # get file names from find, call them icon
          sudo rsync -azuvhE -n icon # copy each file to ....
          tango:/jobs/prime/Item/icon # this folder on tango
```

This should be an equivalent command:

```
sudo find -name "*.jpg" -exec rsync -azuvhE -n {} tango:/jobs/prime/Item/ \;
```

Comment: Btw I am curious, since I am on the server alphis, do I need to do another cross file referencing from tango to alphis? Currently my terminal is displayed as `tnt@alphis find -name "*.jpg" | xargs -I icon sudo rsync -azuvhE -n icon tango:/jobs/prime/Item/icon` and so, do I need to change my ssh so that it will be: `tnt@tango find -name "*.jpg" | xargs -I icon sudo rsync -azuvhE -n icon alphis:/jobs/prime/Item/icon`?

Comment: @user3212246, xargs is necessary because you want to get the names from stdin and read it as arguments with rsync. I added another method that does not use xargs.

Comment: @user3212246, you don't want to be on tango if you want to copy files you find on alphis.

Comment: Can I take it that running the command once will add/ check the file differences from both sides? (Pardon me my breakdown wording) If it is true, then I can say that if I am in server Alphis, then the code line behind will be directed to server Tango:..., or, likewise if I am in server Tango, I will just change it to Alphis:...?

Comment: it will only update the remote directory. see: http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man1/rsync.1.php. The command updates existing files on the remote system if the local system has updated versions.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but upon reading the link you have given me, can I say that rsync is a one-way street?

Comment: That's right, you can run it twice though: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1602324/390913

Comment: I see. I keep having the misinterpretation in my code that it can run both ways as it checks and update on the file differences... Well, I guess this would means I would need to run it again. Thanks!