# How to make a bash function to run a bidirectional rsync

Tags: bash, rsync

I have a local folder and a remote one on a server with ssh connection. I don't have admin privileges so installing new packages are not possible to use unison for example. I have to sync these two folders quite often and they are also big. From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1602348/4999991) I know that to sync in both sides I have to rsync twice. once from server to local:

```
rsync -Przzuve ssh user@server:/path/to/remote/folder/* /path/to/local/folder
```

and then the other way around, from local to server

```
rsync -Przzuve ssh /path/to/local/folder/* user@server:/path/to/remote/folder
```

What I want to have is a single command like:

```
rsyncb /path/to/local/folder user@server:/path/to/remote/folder
```

To just sync the content of two folders in both directions in one command without worrying about the -* options and /* at the end of the first path...

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7131683/4999991) about making a bash function with given arguments but I do not understand how to implement what I want. I would appreciate if you could help me with this.

Comment: Aliases can't process parameters, you need to use a function.

Comment: The first answer in the question you linked to says that in the first sentence.

Comment: @Barmar thanks a lot for your comment and downvote

Comment: Could you explain what part of the linked question is unclear / how you tried to apply its advice and failed? Right now it's unclear what part of what you're trying to do isn't already answered there (and thus why this isn't simply a duplicate). Please be as specific as possible (ie. "the answer advises Y, but when I try that I get Z").

Comment: @CharlesDuffy It was not clear to me for example how to add the `/*` part at the end of the path and other issues

Comment: If adding the `/*` is your problem, it sounds more like you have a question about how to concatenate strings to form an argument list than like a question about bash functions. If what you really had is, say, two or three separate questions, then they should be broken out and searched for individually (I'd say "and asked" if the search failed, but we already have perfectly good knowledgebase entries about string concatenation, and probably whatever the other specific points of confusion were).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for your comments. There were more questions which I didn't know how to ask. I'm a bash novice. I will consider your points next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just define a function.

```
rsyncb() {
    rsync -Przzuve ssh "$1"/* "$2"
    rsync -Przzuve ssh "$2"/* "$1"
}
```

Then use it like this:
`rsyncb user@server:/path/to/remote/dir /path/to/local/dir`

Comment: You should quote the variables, in case they contain whitespace.

Comment: @BenHarris does it have to be 3 parameters?

Comment: @Foad you can set it up however you want.

Comment: @Foad that should work too, as long as you include the `user@server:` in the path.

Comment: @BenHarris the `ssh` part is not required?

Comment: @Foad no, it's automatic when using the `user@server` syntax.

Comment: @BenHarris in my case ssh was required. I will add an edit. I would appreciate if you could take a look.

Comment: I wish there was also a way to do not ask for the server password twice!

Comment: create an ssh key (`ssh-keygen`) and then copy your public key to the server with `ssh-copy-id`. you won't be asked for the password at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164120/discussion-between-ben-harris-and-foad).

Comment: I suggest removing the asterisk so that dotfiles are synced too.